# How to give validation of mobile number which is already in a database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have driver_info table, In that i want to insert a record of various drivers of parameters driver_name,vehicle_no,license_no,mob_no,photo etc. respectively, but i have to avoid duplication of mobile number, I am trying below code for checking duplication of mobile number but it doesn't work and gives "successfully registered!!!" message.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$m_no = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['m_no']);
$query1 = "SELECT mob_no FROM driver_info WHERE mob_no='$m_no'";
    $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($result1)){
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Mobile_No is Already Exist...."); location.href="signup.php"';
    echo '</script>';
    }
    else{

$v = $_POST['n'];   
$name = $_POST['nme'];
$v_no = $_POST['v_no'];
$l_no = $_POST['l_no'];
$m_no = $_POST['m_no'];
$photo = $_FILES['txtphoto']['name'];
$stat = $_POST['stat'];

$query ="INSERT INTO
driver_info(driver_name,vehicle_no,license_no,mob_no,photo,status,seller_id)
VALUES('$name','$v_no','$l_no','$m_no','$photo','$stat','$v')";

$result = mysql_query($query);

copy($_FILES['txtphoto']['tmp_name'],"Picture/".$photo);
if($result==1)
    {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("successfully registered!!!"); location.href="index.php"';
    echo '</script>';
    }
    else
    {
      echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Something Went Wrong!!! :("); location.href="index.php"';
    echo '</script>';
    }
    //mysql_close(@mysql_connect);
}   
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things.

First of all, you should abandon the deprecated mysql_* functions and move on to mysqli or PDO, and don't forget to use prepared statements.

Seondly:
If I am not mistaken, your mob_num column is of the integer type, if so you should get rid of the single quotes here:
mob_no='$m_no'

Thirdly:

With your insert statement you should be weary of those single quotes you put around you values, they may cause problems related to datatypes.

Lastly:

Instead of using the singlequote system you have in place right now, it's better to use string concatenation to avoid all errors, I'll use `$query1` as an example:

What you have right now:
`$query1 = "SELECT mob_no FROM driver_info WHERE mob_no='$m_no'";`
What it should be (if you want to keep the single quote thing): 
`$query1 = "SELECT mob_no FROM driver_info WHERE mob_no='".$m_no."'";`
And what it should be if you no longer want to use the single quotes (depending on datatypes):
`$query1 = "SELECT mob_no FROM driver_info WHERE mob_no=".$m_no;

Small tip for debugging, since you currently do not use prepared statements or the like, you can actually do this: `echo $query1;` to see the whole query with the actual value, this way you can see how the value appears in the statement and you can easily run it in PHPMyAdmin and the like to make sure you don't have any errors in your SQL prior to modifying your source code.